# Return even if searched result partially matches the array elements in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am getting the following in `@name  = ["document1", "Public", "Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"]`

I did `@name.include?("Folder")` it checks for the exact match. But I want it to return

```
["Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder 33"]
```

And if I search for `document` it should return `["document1"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = ["document1", "Public", "Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"]
> a.select { |str| str.include?('Folder') }
#=> ["Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"]
> a.select { |str| str.include?('document') }
#=> ["document1"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

> Returns an array of every element in enum for which Pattern ===
>   element. If the optional block is supplied, each matching element is
>   passed to it, and the block’s result is stored in the output array.

```
>> ["document1", "Public", "Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"].grep(/^Folder/)
=> ["Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"]
>> ["document1", "Public", "Folder11", "Folder22", "Folder33"].grep(/^document/)
=> ["document1"]
```